# Possible to Make This Method Generic(Takes In Crystal Report Objects)

Tags: c#, generics, crystal-reports, .net-2.0

I have a block of code that looks like this

```
CrystalReport2 report1 = new CrystalReport2();
                    report1.SetParameterValue("@StartDate", startDate);
                    report1.SetParameterValue("@EndDate", endDate);
                    report1.SetParameterValue("@show", 1);
                    report1.SetParameterValue("@name", name);


                    string fullFileName = //filename;
                    report1.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, fullFileName);
                    report1.Close();
                    report1.Dispose();
```

I have a couple of these reports and the block of code is almost identical for each one of the reports. They all use the same set of parameters and get exported the same way.

They all generate different data sets(hence why I have a few reports).

So I can only see one like changing for each one

```
CrystalReport2 report1 = new CrystalReport2();
CrystalReport3 report2 = new CrystalReport3();
```

So is there away I can make the above code a method that can take any report in?

Comment: Do `CrystalReport2` and `CrystalReport3` derive from a single base class, or implement an interface?

Comment: Well they are auto generated files but looking into them I see ReportClass they both inherit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a helper like this:

```
    public static void MyReportsCommonTasks(
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass report,
        DateTime startDate,
        DateTime endDate,
        String name,
        String fullFileName)
    {
        report.SetParameterValue("@StartDate", startDate);
        report.SetParameterValue("@EndDate", endDate);
        report.SetParameterValue("@show", 1);
        report.SetParameterValue("@name", name);
        report.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, fullFileName);
        report.Close();
        report.Dispose();
    }
```

Note that this is possible because the reports extend from `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass`

Follow the example of how to instantiate the report within the method:

```
    public static void MyReportsCommonTasks<R>(
        DateTime startDate,
        DateTime endDate,
        String name,
        String fullFileName) 
        where R : CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass, new()
    {
        ReportClass report = new R();
        report.SetParameterValue("@StartDate", startDate);
        report.SetParameterValue("@EndDate", endDate);
        report.SetParameterValue("@show", 1);
        report.SetParameterValue("@name", name);
        report.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.Excel, fullFileName);
        report.Close();
        report.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Right did not even occur to me to look inside the autogenerated crystal report as not I do see they inherit ReportClass which seems to have all the above in the base class. Why use a helper like this vs just a method?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was not very clear. I meant that you can use a "helper method", which may be in a "base abstract class" or be a static method in another class.

Comment: On a side note do you know how I can create a new instance of say CrystalReports1 with using the ReportClass. Like say if I pass in Report1 what becomes Reportclass can I then take ReportClass and make it into a new instance of Report1. I tried to use Type but that just gave me some error saying it can't find Report1 in my .dll